# I am unable to Add to Cart as Anonymous User using session key

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I am developing a ecommerce website using Python Django framework. Code is proper and actively working when user login but not working as a guest. I am unable to Add to Cart as Anonymous User using session key.

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_qty = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
```

cart.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from buyjoi.models import Product, Cart
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def addtocart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)

            if (product_check):
                if (Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, product_id=prod_id)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': "Product Already in Cart"})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))

                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty:
                        Cart.objects.create(
                            user=request.user, product_id=prod_id, product_qty=prod_qty)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Product added successfully"})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Only " + str(product_check.quantity) + " quantity available"})

            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': "No such product found"})
        else:
            request.session['product_id']
            prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)

            if (product_check):
                if (Cart.objects.filter(product_id=prod_id, session_key=request.session.session_key)):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': "Product Already in Cart"})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))

                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty:
                        Cart.objects.create(
                            product_id=prod_id, product_qty=prod_qty, session_key=request.session.session_key)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Product added successfully"})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "Only " + str(product_check.quantity) + " quantity available"})

            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': "No such product found"})
    return redirect("/")


def viewcart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
    context = {
        'cart': cart
    }
    return render(request, "cart.html", context)


def updatecart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        if (Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
            prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
            cart = Cart.objects.get(product_id=prod_id, user=request.user)
            cart.product_qty = prod_qty
            cart.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': "Updated Successfully"})
    return redirect('/')


def deletecartitem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        prod_id = int(request.POST.get('product_id'))
        if(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id)):
            cartitem = Cart.objects.get(product_id=prod_id, user=request.user)
            cartitem.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'status:"Deleted Successfully"'})
    return redirect('/')
```

I was trying to use Add to Cart facility as a guest using session key, and if login, then for same.